# How to Present Special Characters with Puppeteer API

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

How can I show special signs in a screenshot that was taken using the Puppeteer API?

You can see an image for example that was taken with Puppeteer and can't show some of the chars in the page:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the [`fonts-wqy-zenhei` font package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/fonts/fonts-wqy-zenhei) on your system to render the characters properly.

I was able to successfully render the fonts in Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt install fonts-wqy-zenhei
```

If you are using Heroku, you can use the [puppeteer-heroku-buildpack](https://github.com/CoffeeAndCode/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack) to render Chinese, Japanese, or Korean characters.

Additionally, if you are wanting to support emojis, you can use the [EmojiOne Font](https://github.com/emojione/emojione/tree/master/extras/fonts#emojione-fonts).

Comment: how about in production env? the emojis actually works on my machine - the problem is when I deploying it to me heroku server. any solution for that?

Comment: @obiwankenoobi You may need to use the [puppeteer-heroku-buildpack](https://github.com/CoffeeAndCode/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack) to render Chinese, Japanese, or Korean characters.

Comment: I actually already use it but with the with the one from the original repo [here](https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack) is your fork support the font?

Comment: @obiwankenoobi Yes, the buildpack I recommended includes the `fonts-wqy-zenhei` font, which is the font you need to display the characters properly on the web page.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! I will try it right now and update you with the results! (:

Comment: one question - should I leave the old one or should I delete it ?

Comment: so after some tests I can confirm - it added some languages but not emojis. There is anything to do with that? thanks!

Comment: @obiwankenoobi I would consider reading [Running Puppeteer on Heroku](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku), and also look into using the [EmojiOne Font](https://github.com/emojione/emojione/tree/master/extras/fonts#emojione-fonts) to support emojis.